# Problem re-factoring multiple timer countdown

Tags: jquery

I create my multiple timer countdown from easy or simple script. [entire code](http://jsfiddle.net/jowan/6jkSJ/)

The problem's happen 
when i want to add timer countdown again

i have to declare 
variable current_total_second

CODE:

```
elapsed_seconds= tampilkan("#time1");
```

and variable timer who set with setInterval..

```
timer= setInterval(function() {
   if (elapsed_seconds != 0){
       elapsed_seconds = elapsed_seconds - 1;
       $('#time1').text(get_elapsed_time_string(elapsed_seconds))
   }else{
       $('#time1').parent().slideUp('slow', function(){
           $(this).find('.post').text("Post has been deleted");
       })
       $('#time1').parent().slideDown('slow');
       clearInterval(timer);
   }
}, 1000);
```

i've already know about re-factoring and try different way
but i'm stack to re-factoring this code
i want implement flexibelity to it..
when i add more of timer countdown..
script do it automatically or dynamically without i have to add a bunch of code..
and the code become clear and more efficient.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably more efficient using a single timer like so...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
     body {
        padding: 10%;
      }

      hr {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        height: 6px;
        background: black;
      }

      .clock {
          margin: 0px;
          padding: 8px 8px;
          background-color: whitesmoke;
          color: red;    
      }

      .post {
          margin: 0px;
          padding: 8px 8px;
          background: white;
          /*border-bottom: 4px solid black;*/
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a class="addTimer">Add Timer</a> | Timer count: <span class="timerCount">0</span><span class="info"></span>
    <div class="container">
    </div>    
  </body>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function get_elapsed_time_string(total_seconds) {
      function pretty_time_string(num) {
      return ( num < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + num;
      }

          var hours = Math.floor(total_seconds / 3600);
           total_seconds = total_seconds % 3600;

          var minutes = Math.floor(total_seconds / 60);
          total_seconds = total_seconds % 60;

          var seconds = Math.floor(total_seconds);

          hours = pretty_time_string(hours);
          minutes = pretty_time_string(minutes);
          seconds = pretty_time_string(seconds);

          var currentTimeString = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;        
          return currentTimeString;
    }

    $(function() {
      var timer = null;
      var timerCount = 0;

      $(".addTimer").click(function(e) {
        $("<hr /><div class=\"timer\" data-remaining=\"10\" data-expired=\"0\"><div class=\"clock\">00:00:10</div><div class=\"post\">Lorem Ipsum</div></div>").appendTo($(".container"));

        timerCount++;
        $(".timerCount").text(timerCount);

        if (timer === null) {
          $(".info").text(" | ticker created");
          timer = setInterval(function() {
            $(".container > .timer").each(function() {
              var remainingSeconds = parseInt($(this).attr("data-remaining"), 10);
              if (remainingSeconds > 1) {
                remainingSeconds--;
                $(this).attr("data-remaining", remainingSeconds);
                $(this).find(".clock").text(get_elapsed_time_string(remainingSeconds));
              } else {
                if ($(this).attr("data-expired") === "0") {
                  remainingSeconds--;
                  $(this).attr("data-remaining", remainingSeconds);
                  $(this).find(".clock").text(get_elapsed_time_string(remainingSeconds));
                  $(this).slideUp("slow", function() {
                    $(this).find(".post").text("Post has been deleted");
                    $(this).slideDown("slow");
                    $(this).attr("data-expired", "1");

                    timerCount--;
                    $(".timerCount").text(timerCount);

                    if (timerCount === 0) {
                      $(".info").text(" | ticker destroyed");
                      clearInterval(timer);
                      timer = null;
                    }
                  });
                }
              }
            });
          }, 1000);
        } else {
          $(".info").text(" | using existing ticker");
        }
      });


    });
  </script>
</html>
```

In this code,I only have 1 ticker running at all time (only 1 setInterval) and using data- attribute to keep track of how many seconds left for each timer and if the timer has expired.
In this way, I can add as many timer as I want since all the necessary metadata about the timer is in the timer itself.

On each tick, I'll just go through each existing timer, inspect its data-remaining attribute and update the timer div accordingly.  if it expires, then do your animation.  When all the timers are done, clean up the interval.

Give it a try...

Comment: thanks jimmy... your code imagine me make my multiple timer countdown